# Why does 'notify' wake up all waiting threads although only one thread should be affected?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

In the following code two consumer threads start and become waiting. The producer thread starts (very likely) after that and calls 'notify'. All threads use the producer as monitor.

```
Thread producer = new Thread() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.printf("notify at %d %n", getId());
            notify();
        }
    }
};

Runnable consumer = () -> {
    try {
        synchronized (producer) {
            long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
            System.out.printf("wait at %d %n", id);
            producer.wait();
            System.out.printf("awakened: %d %n", id);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

Stream.generate( () -> consumer )
        .limit(2)
        .map(Thread::new)
        .forEach(Thread::start);

Thread.sleep(3000); // consumer threads are (likely) waiting

producer.start();
```

From javadoc for [Object.notify](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()):

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.

The code produces this (or similar) output:

```
  wait at 13 
  wait at 14 
  notify at 12 
  awakened: 13 
  awakened: 14
```

The point is that both consumer threads are awakened, not just one of them. Why?

Compiled and tested with OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.5+10) under Windows 10, 64-bit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that instead of an arbitrary `Object` you use a `Thread` as the monitor.

`Thread` uses signals internally as documented in [`Thread.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)):

> As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

The general suggestion is to always use dedicated objects to `wait`/`notify` on that no other code can get access to to avoid "spurious" notifies or waits like this.